# How do I delete fileds in request object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I make request to server from angularjs controller to get an object and I want to delete a field in the object before view displays it. Folloiwng is my code

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.order = Orders.get({
        orderId: $stateParams.orderId
    });
    delete $scope.order._id;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.order));
};
```

it prints

```
{"$promise":{},"$resolved":false}
```

it doesn't delete the id field. My view shows even _id of my object. How do I delete that field?

Following is my services file

'use strict';

```
//Orders service used for communicating with the orders REST endpoints
angular.module('orders').factory('Orders', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('orders/:orderId', {
            orderId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

When I change findOne() to

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    Orders.get({
        orderId: $stateParams.orderId
        }).success(function(res)//(this is line number 56)
        {
            delete res.data._id;
            $scope.order = res.data;
    });
};
```

I get this error in console

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.findOne (http://localhost:3000/modules/orders/controllers/orders.client.controller.js:56:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10903:21
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12811:28)
    at pre (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:20125:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6732:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6146:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6042:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3905:9
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6752:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6146:13) <section data-ng-controller="OrdersController" data-ng-init="findOne()" class="ng-scope">angular.js:10126 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: `Orders.get` is probably returning a promise, which you immediately log to the console. In any case, I don't understand the entire "delete before the View displays" - just don't render it in the View

Comment: I can avoid rendering the view but I was curious to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the function to

```
    $scope.findOne = function() {
        var order = Orders.get({
            orderId: $stateParams.orderId
        }, function()
        {
            order.order_type = 'new';
        });
         $scope.order = order;
    };
```

and it worked. I wonder if the syntax is changed in angularjs update. Similar syntax is mentioned in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource. Though I could not figure out the reason other answers with success callback didn't work .

Answer (score 1):

The Orders.get function returns a promise, having this in mind your code should look something like this:

```
Orders.get({orderId: $stateParams.orderId}).then(function(order) {
  delete order._id;
  $scope.order = order;
});
```

Comment: when I change it to the way you mentioned it gives errorTypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.findOne (http://localhost:3000/modules/orders/controllers/orders.client.controller.js:56:7)

Comment: could you give me a copy of your code in a pastebin?

Comment: and could you give me the result of a console.log(data) (or res)? The problem could be on the data you recieve on your get request. Maybe the key you want to delete doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

get by default returns a promise object. The way to do this is

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    Orders.get({
        orderId: $stateParams.orderId
        }).success(function(res)
        {
            delete res.data._id;
            $scope.order = res.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: when I change it to the way you mentioned it gives errorTypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.findOne (http://localhost:3000/modules/orders/controllers/orders.client.controller.js:56:7)

Comment: @raju You can add a break point at the 56 line number as the stack trace begins from there. Also, it would help if you tell us what is at line number 56. I am assuming it is the delete statement there. If so, it could be because res.data is invalid or res.data._id is a private field (by convention in JavaScript) and angular might be blocking it. Best thing to do is put a break point and check.

Comment: no line 56 is the success line. GET request gets successfully executed.

Comment: I am thinking success method is not defined but it should be!